# Symfony2 locale ignored for base twig template

Tags: php, symfony, twig, listener, translation

## Situation

I'm setting locale on a listener listening on `kernel.request` like this:

```
<?php
// ...
class LocaleListener
{
    //...
    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        if (!$event->isMasterRequest()) {
            return;
        }

        // [...] some logic to get $locale
        $request->setLocale($locale);
    }
}
?>
```

Then, I have two twig templates, a base and a base-extending-template. Base template (`base.html.twig`):

```
<html>
<body>
    {{ 'some.translation'|trans({}, 'messages') }}

    {% block body %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

And the base-extending-template (`profile.html.twig`):

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    {{ 'some.translation'|trans({}, 'messages') }}
{% endblock %}
```

The Controller of the route will render profile.html.twig:

```
<?php
// ...
class SomeController extends Controller
{
    //...
    public function someAction()
    {
        return $this->render('::profile.html.twig');
    }
}
?>
```

Nothing special, all very simple...

## Problem

The rendered template extending the base (`profile.html.twig`) is using the locale for the translation set in the listener. Unfortunately the base template (`base.html.twig`) IS NOT. Even when I dump `{{ dump(app.request.locale) }}` on the base template, it shows the correct locale set in the listener...

What do I miss?

---

## Edit

Oh, and I'm using Symfony v2.7.11.

Comment: Could it be a cache issue? Maybe try clearing `app/cache/dev` and/or `app/cache/prod`. Regarding the locale, check the event priority. [Creating a LocaleListener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/session/locale_sticky_session.html#creating-a-localelistener) states that you need to be extra careful here (see line #36).

Comment: about the priority: your listener must be registered after both `LocaleListener` and `TranslatorListener`, so `<= 9`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Working solution**: Created the LocaleListener exactly like documented [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/session/locale_sticky_session.html#creating-a-localelistener) (hint by Yoshi).

**Addendum**: I wanted the locale stored in User's entity to be used, so I had to create a `InteractiveLoginListener` ([class file](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/d66890ad3489e18be153502c5ccc3f2bf5cce442/Security/InteractiveLoginListener.php)). As of version 1.3.6, there's (like 2.0-alpha, even though not documented) an event called `security.interactive_login` which had to be injected:

```
app.interactive_login_listener:
    class: AppBundle\EventListener\Security\InteractiveLoginListener
    arguments: ['@fos_user.user_manager', '@session']
    tags:
        - { name: 'kernel.event_listener', event: 'security.interactive_login', method: 'onSecurityInteractiveLogin' }
```